# Installing Windows instead of Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Alright so kind of a long story, but basically I had a laptop with Windows 7 on it, and the hard drive failed. So I bought a cheap SSD and installed Ubuntu on it (because who wants to pay for windows for a test.) I've been using Ubuntu for a little bit now, and I'm just getting sick of it. I have no idea how to use the little terminal thing and whenever I want to install something I just copy and paste lines into it from whatever forum has an installation guide. I'm trying to upgrade back to Windows, but I can't seem to get anything to work. I bought a Windows 7 Home Premium Key, and I have an ISO downloaded on my computer, but I can't figure out how to format a USB stick to get it to boot. Is there any easy way to install Windows?

P.S. I don't need to backup anything on my computer, I have the few files that I need saved to my Google Drive, and I also don't want to do a dual-boot thing, just to switch completely from Ubuntu to Windows

Answer (score 0):

At first create a bootable USB following this [link](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/). (from Step2)

When you get an option for selecting a drive to install windows delete all partitions and install Windows over it.

That's it windows installer will take care of the rest for you.